# Why https is more widely used rather than SSH on client-server communication?

Tags: http, networking, ssh

Both SSH and https are secure protocol used for computers to communicate. But why is https more widely used on client/browser-server communication? Any technical reasons?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is basically the secure version of HTTP, which is used for web access.
SSH  is basically the secure version of telnet, which is used for terminal access.  Since web traffic is more common than terminal, HTTPS is more common.